# Linking Boost in Makefile?

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

I know this question has been asked a million times but I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm working with a Makefile written by someone else:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -gdwarf-3 -std=c++0x -rdynamic #
JEMALLOC=deps/jemalloc-5.1.0
NNMSG=deps/nng-1.3.2
BOOST=deps/boost_1_67_0
CRYPTOPP=deps/crypto
SQLITE=deps/sqlite-autoconf-3290000/build

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp .h

SRC_DIRS = ./ ./benchmarks/ ./client/ ./transport/ ./system/ ./statistics/ ./blockchain/ ./db/ ./smart_contracts/ ./data_structures
DEPS = -I. -I./benchmarks -I./client/ -I./transport -I./system -I./statistics -I./blockchain -I./smart_contracts  -I./data_structures -I$(JEMALLOC)/include -I$(NNMSG)/include -I$(BOOST) -I$(CRYPTOPP) -I./db -I$(SQLITE)/include 

CFLAGS += $(DEPS) -D NOGRAPHITE=1 -Werror -Wno-sizeof-pointer-memaccess
LDFLAGS = -Wall -L. -L$(NNMSG)/lib -L$(JEMALLOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(JEMALLOC)/lib -pthread -gdwarf-3 -lrt -std=c++0x -L$(CRYPTOPP) -L$(SQLITE)/lib
LDFLAGS += $(CFLAGS)
LIBS = -lnng -lanl -ljemalloc -lcryptopp -lsqlite3 -ldl

DB_MAINS = ./client/client_main.cpp  ./unit_tests/unit_main.cpp
CL_MAINS = ./system/main.cpp ./unit_tests/unit_main.cpp
UNIT_MAINS = ./system/main.cpp ./client/client_main.cpp 

CPPS_DB = $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(filter-out $(DB_MAINS), $(wildcard $(dir)*.cpp))) 
CPPS_CL = $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(filter-out $(CL_MAINS), $(wildcard $(dir)*.cpp))) 
CPPS_UNIT = $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(filter-out $(UNIT_MAINS), $(wildcard $(dir)*.cpp))) 

#CPPS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS_DB = $(addprefix obj/, $(notdir $(CPPS_DB:.cpp=.o)))
OBJS_CL = $(addprefix obj/, $(notdir $(CPPS_CL:.cpp=.o)))
OBJS_UNIT = $(addprefix obj/, $(notdir $(CPPS_UNIT:.cpp=.o)))

#NOGRAPHITE=1

all:rundb runcl 


.PHONY: deps_db
deps:$(CPPS_DB)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^ > obj/deps
    sed '/^[^ ]/s/^/obj\//g' obj/deps > obj/deps.tmp
    mv obj/deps.tmp obj/deps
-include obj/deps

rundb : $(OBJS_DB)
    $(CC) -static -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
./obj/%.o: transport/%.cpp
    $(CC) -static -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: benchmarks/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: blockchain/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: system/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: statistics/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: client/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: db/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: smart_contracts/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<

runcl : $(OBJS_CL)
    $(CC) -static -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

./obj/%.o: transport/%.cpp
    $(CC) -static -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: benchmarks/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: blockchain/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: system/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: statistics/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: client/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<
./obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f obj/*.o obj/.depend rundb runcl runsq unit_test
```

What I'm attempting to do is place a header only library `crow_all.h` into a my file `system/client_thread.cpp`. Its worth noting that the crow library has this path `/deps/crow_all.h`.

I've tried appending `-lpthread -L$(BOOST)/libs -lboost_system` the `LDFLAGS` flag but I still manage to get this error:

```
/mnt/d/programs/ExpoLab/ResilientDB/deps/boost_1_67_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:230: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

Furthermore, I *think* my compiler is picking up my system version of the boost library?? I only say that since when I use `Make` when inside a docker container, I get a different error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
```

Any advice would be amazing.. this is pretty frustrating :(

Comment: Do you use boost as static libraries?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Since I'm not familiar with this how would I check that?

Comment: Just  look at the folder `deps/boost_1_67_0` to see if there are `.so` files or `.a` files named like `libboost_system.a` or `libboost_system.so`

Comment: Sure thing, I went ahead and used `ls -R | grep` and no files came up with the `.so` extension. My supervisor did mention this version of boost was linked statically though.

Comment: So it's the root cause, you are trying to link dynamic libraries, give a try with some commands like this: `g++ -o"acmserver"  ./src/acmserver.o ... ./src/server.o \
  /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a /usr/local/lib/boost_filesystem \
  ... -lGL ...`